# Map two data frames in a certain condition

Tags: r

I already asked  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733571/map-two-data-frames-in-r-in-condition-that-the-time-of-one-of-them-is-earlier-th)

But now my current problem is slightly different that I couldn't use this solution or figure out .  I'd like the data from data set 1 that occurred before dataset 2 and this is my data:

```
 # Dataset 1 (dts1)

     UserID   date   Hour     Events    
  1    5  25/07/2016  02:31      8         
  2    5  30/07/2016  02:42      6      
  3    4  23/07/2016  07:52      9         
  4   14  24/07/2016  03:02      5         
  5   17  25/07/2016  09:12      10        
  6    4  22/07/2016  03:22      4
```

and

```
   # Dataset 2 (dts2)

    UserID       date   Hour      transactions     
 1     5    25/07/2016  02:29      4         
 2     4    24/07/2016  02:42      2       
 3     5    25/07/2016  02:52      3         
 4     6    24/07/2016  03:02      4         
 5     6    25/07/2016  03:12      1        
 6    14    26/07/2016  03:22      3
```

So, I wish to compare those dataset from dataset 1 and only add those happened before dataset 2. In other words, I want to make sure that I do not count those events that happened after the last transaction of a user. The Ideal output is as follows:

```
    #output 

   UserID   Events      transaction 

    5         8         4,3
    4         9,4       2
   14         5         3
   17         10        NA
```

In the above example, I made sure that I removed event 6 for user 5 because  it happened after his last transaction.

Comment: Would you please explain why did you downvote this question? I'm recently active here and not very familiar

Comment: The downvote wasn't me, but usually it would be good practice to show what you have tried to do and where you got stuck.  See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a modification of @dimitris_ps answer for your previous question. If he chooses to answer, I will gladly delete mine.

The main difference between this problem and your previous problem is that we now want all `dts1` events that are before the **last** `dts2` transaction for each specific `UserID`. Therefore, we want to `group_by` the `UserID` first and then `filter` for only those rows where the `dts1` event times are less than the last `dts2` transaction time. Then we can `summarise` both unique `Events` and `transactions`, still grouped by `UserID`.

The code is:

```
library(dplyr)

## I will not use the lubridate package, instead I will convert the time
## using as.POSIXct
dts1$time <- as.POSIXct(paste(dts1$date, dts1$Hour), format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
dts2$time <- as.POSIXct(paste(dts2$date, dts2$Hour), format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")

# first join the two data.frames by UserID.
result <- left_join(dts1, dts2, by="UserID") %>%

# all subsequent processing is grouped by the UserID because we 
# want to compare the last transaction time to the Event times
# for each UserID.
group_by(UserID) %>%

# apply the filtering condition dts1 Event must be before last dts2 transaction.
# Note that we keep rows for which there is no row in  
# dts2 for a UserID in dts1. This is the case for UserID=17.
filter(is.na(time.y) | last(time.y) > time.x) %>% 

# summarise Events and transactions
summarise(Events = toString(unique(Events)), transactions = toString(unique(transactions)))
```

The results are:

```
print(result)
## A tibble: 4 x 3
##  UserID Events transactions
##   <int>  <chr>        <chr>
##1      4   9, 4            2
##2      5      8         4, 3
##3     14      5            3
##4     17     10           NA
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, It helped a lot

Answer (score 2):

We first convert the time to POSIX class.

```
dts1$time <- strptime(paste(dts1$date, dts1$Hour), format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
dts2$time <- strptime(paste(dts2$date, dts2$Hour), format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

Next step is to make the `transactions` column. We do so by first sorting `dts2` by time (from latest to earliest), then using the `by()` function to subset `dts` by `UserID` and taking the first row from each subset.  We then use `tapply` to retrieve `transactions` for each `UserID`.

```
dts2 <- dts2[order(dts2$time, decreasing=TRUE), ]
out <- do.call(rbind, by(dts2[,c("UserID","time")], dts2$UserID, head, 1))
out$transactions <- tapply(dts2$transactions, dts2$UserID, c)
```

Finally, we build the `Events` column using the rule you described.

```
out$Events <- sapply(1:nrow(out), function(i) {
    User2 <- out$UserID[i]
    time2 <- out$time[i]
    rows <- which(dts1$UserID==User2 & dts1$time<time2)
    if (length(rows)>0) {            
        dts1$Events[rows]
    } else {
        NA
    }
})
```

Result:

```
> out
   UserID                time transactions Events
4       4 2016-07-24 02:42:00            2   9, 4
5       5 2016-07-25 02:52:00         3, 4      8
6       6 2016-07-25 03:12:00         1, 4     NA
14     14 2016-07-26 03:22:00            3      5
```

Note that since User 17 is not in `dts2`, it doesn't appear in `out`.